# the value of double when getter setter is used

Tags: c#, getter-setter

Lets suppose i have a field with short defined getter setter like following:

```
public double MyDouble { get; set; }
```

I want to check this MyDouble value if it is set or not. i can not check like this:

```
if(MyDouble == null) .... else ....
```

Because double variables can not get null values. So how can i check this value if it is set or not? Do i have to use a second variable holding the isSet state or is there any default value for the double type?
Thanks.

Comment: lets say i assume that if the variable value is 0 then it means it is not set. But what will i do if the value is set excatly to 0 ? How can i seperate these stuations?

Comment: You can't I just stated the default value. But making it an nullable is in my opinion the best way to go. If for whatever reason you can't have an nullable, then the isSet state is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*System.Double* is a *struct* (*value type*).

It cannot be *null*.

You neeed to make it *nullable*:

```
double? MyDouble { get; set; }
```

More on Nullable Types : [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use Nullable Value Types. A nullable value type can be set to null, so you can check if the double has a null value or not:

```
double? myVal = null;
if(myVal==null)
   Console.WriteLine("NULL DOUBLE ENCOUNTERED !");
```

Answer (score 0):

Default value for double is 0 but it might possible that you want to set this value to 0 at later stage so checking for 0 seems not good.
What you can do is set the value in its constructor to -

```
MyDouble = Double.MinValue;
```

and check in your setter

```
if(MyDouble == Double.MinValue) .... else ....
```

`Double.MinValue is -1.7976931348623157E+308` which is highly unlikely that you will be setting in your class.

Comment: What if you may want to set the value of `MyDouble` to `Double.MinValue` anyway?

Comment: That's what i said its highly unlikely. Then you can't even use nullable double. You may counter that what if i want to set the value to null. `What if` never ends mate.

Comment: checking null value is better than checking Double.MinValue and checking Double.MinValue is better than checking 0

Comment: It never ends unless the private backing field of `MyDouble` is `Nullable` and the public property is not. But I agree it doesn't really match the question anymore in such a case.

Comment: @Guillaume- The perfect answer is what lies in your comment above for me for having private backing field propery as nullable and actual property doesn't.. Would have given +1 on your answer.. :)

Comment: If one wants to use a "magic" value, instead of `MinValue` one can also choose `NaN`. It has the advantage that if, by accident, you _use_ the value, all subsequent results will be `NaN`. In that respect it is like a `null`. Also `NaN` can never be less than or greater than any number. On the other hand, `MinValue` is a "proper" number, it is less than (according to `<`) most other `double` values, though greater than (`>`) than `double.NegativeInfinity`.